# How to fix Luasandbox extension error Mediawiki

Tags: lua, cpanel, mediawiki, scribunto

I'm currently making a wiki with mediawiki 1.39 on a hosted server, I decided to enable scribunto through my cpanel in order to utilize modules, i selected luasandbox as my default engine, and wrote the code in the LocalSettings.php as:

```
wfLoadExtension( 'Scribunto' );
$wgScribuntoDefaultEngine = 'luasandbox'; // Use LuaSandbox as the default engine
```

Everything seemed fine, when i decide to create a module page, pasting one from wikipedia, when i clicked on save page, it threw me an internal error. It read:

```
[ZQkYSxr_nfXN6YUDbjbzjQAAkTM] /index.php?title=Module:For&action=submit Scribunto_LuaInterpreterNotFoundError: The luasandbox extension is not present, this engine cannot be used.

Backtrace:

from /home3/funkinch/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaSandbox/LuaSandboxInterpreter.php(44)
#0 /home3/funkinch/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaSandbox/LuaSandboxInterpreter.php(61): MediaWiki\Extension\Scribunto\Engines\LuaSandbox\LuaSandboxInterpreter::checkLuaSandboxVersion()
#1 /home3/funkinch/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaSandbox/LuaSandboxEngine.php(258): MediaWiki\Extension\Scribunto\Engines\LuaSandbox\LuaSandboxInterpreter->__construct(MediaWiki\Extension\Scribunto\Engines\LuaSandbox\LuaSandboxEngine, array)
#2 /home3/funkinch/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaCommon/LuaEngine.php(131): MediaWiki\Extension\Scribunto\Engines\LuaSandbox\LuaSandboxEngine->newInterpreter()
#3 /home3/funkinch/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaCommon/LuaEngine.php(235): Scribunto_LuaEngine->load()
#4 /home3/funkinch/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaCommon/LuaModule.php(41): Scribunto_LuaEngine->getInterpreter()
#5 /home3/funkinch/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaCommon/LuaModule.php(28): Scribunto_LuaModule->getInitChunk()
#6 /home3/funkinch/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/ScribuntoEngineBase.php(201): Scribunto_LuaModule->validate()
#7 /home3/funkinch/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/ScribuntoContentHandler.php(105): MediaWiki\Extension\Scribunto\ScribuntoEngineBase->validate(string, string)
#8 /home3/funkinch/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/Hooks.php(389): MediaWiki\Extension\Scribunto\ScribuntoContentHandler->validate(MediaWiki\Extension\Scribunto\ScribuntoContent, Title)
#9 /home3/funkinch/public_html/includes/HookContainer/HookContainer.php(338): MediaWiki\Extension\Scribunto\Hooks::validateScript(DerivativeContext, MediaWiki\Extension\Scribunto\ScribuntoContent, Status, string, User, boolean)
#10 /home3/funkinch/public_html/includes/HookContainer/HookContainer.php(137): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookContainer->callLegacyHook(string, array, array, array)
#11 /home3/funkinch/public_html/includes/HookContainer/HookRunner.php(1472): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookContainer->run(string, array)
#12 /home3/funkinch/public_html/includes/editpage/Constraint/EditFilterMergedContentHookConstraint.php(100): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookRunner->onEditFilterMergedContent(DerivativeContext, MediaWiki\Extension\Scribunto\ScribuntoContent, Status, string, User, boolean)
#13 /home3/funkinch/public_html/includes/editpage/Constraint/EditConstraintRunner.php(88): MediaWiki\EditPage\Constraint\EditFilterMergedContentHookConstraint->checkConstraint()
#14 /home3/funkinch/public_html/includes/EditPage.php(2344): MediaWiki\EditPage\Constraint\EditConstraintRunner->checkConstraints()
#15 /home3/funkinch/public_html/includes/EditPage.php(1904): EditPage->internalAttemptSave(array, boolean, boolean)
#16 /home3/funkinch/public_html/includes/EditPage.php(721): EditPage->attemptSave(array)
#17 /home3/funkinch/public_html/includes/actions/EditAction.php(73): EditPage->edit()
#18 /home3/funkinch/public_html/includes/actions/SubmitAction.php(38): EditAction->show()
#19 /home3/funkinch/public_html/includes/MediaWiki.php(542): SubmitAction->show()
#20 /home3/funkinch/public_html/includes/MediaWiki.php(322): MediaWiki->performAction(Article, Title)
#21 /home3/funkinch/public_html/includes/MediaWiki.php(904): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#22 /home3/funkinch/public_html/includes/MediaWiki.php(562): MediaWiki->main()
#23 /home3/funkinch/public_html/index.php(50): MediaWiki->run()
#24 /home3/funkinch/public_html/index.php(46): wfIndexMain()
#25 {main}
```

I tried messing around the LocalSettings.php and the Cpanel, even putting the luasandbox folder as an extension and reinstalling Scribunto as 1.40, but none of it have worked.
If any of you have any experience writting modules for mediawiki, tell me what did you do to enable them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you [install](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/LuaSandbox#Installation) it?

Comment: I installed the https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-php-luasandbox/archive/master.tar.gz snapshot version that was on the mediawiki site, and i dumped the zip on the extensions folder of the wiki in the Cpanel, and tried listing it on the LocalSettings.php. Don't know if it's a separate version i have to download, or if i have to put the zip on another place.

Comment: You need to have luasandbox PHP extension enabled, so that `php -i | grep 'luasandbox'` shows it.
So, you need to have access to your PHP configuration.

Comment: I have access to PHP configuration, but in my case, my cpanel uses MultiPHP Manager  instead of Select PHP version. Could you please tell me, how to enable extensions in php in that case ?

Comment: Update. Solved the problem, just had to install the newest version of Scribunto, it works well now.